# image reel slider - bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used on a webpage a javascript i found online that will slide a few images at a certain time interval.
All went well, i installed it and used it till i noticed that in firefox and in chrome after a few turns of the slider it starts to move very fast and obviously not looking like it supposed to.

Here is the script that i have in the head section:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Set Default State of each portfolio piece
    $(".paging").show();
    $(".paging a:first").addClass("active");

    //Get size of images, how many there are, then determin the size of the image reel.
    var imageWidth = $(".window").width();
    var imageSum = $(".image_reel img").size();
    var imageReelWidth = imageWidth * imageSum;

    //Adjust the image reel to its new size
    $(".image_reel").css({'width' : imageReelWidth});

    //Paging + Slider Function
    rotate = function(){    
        var triggerID = $active.attr("rel") - 1; //Get number of times to slide
        var image_reelPosition = triggerID * imageWidth; //Determines the distance the image reel needs to slide

        $(".paging a").removeClass('active'); //Remove all active class
        $active.addClass('active'); //Add active class (the $active is declared in the rotateSwitch function)

        //Slider Animation
        $(".image_reel").animate({ 
            left: -image_reelPosition
        }, 500 );

    }; 

    //Rotation + Timing Event
    rotateSwitch = function(){      
        play = setInterval(function(){ //Set timer - this will repeat itself every 3 seconds
            $active = $('.paging a.active').next();
            if ( $active.length === 0) { //If paging reaches the end...
                $active = $('.paging a:first'); //go back to first
            }
            rotate(); //Trigger the paging and slider function
        }, 3000); //Timer speed in milliseconds (3 seconds)
    };

    rotateSwitch(); //Run function on launch

    //On Hover
    $(".image_reel a").hover(function() {
        clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
    }, function() {
        rotateSwitch(); //Resume rotation
    }); 

    //On Click
    $(".paging a").click(function() {   
        $active = $(this); //Activate the clicked paging
        //Reset Timer
        clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
        rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
        rotateSwitch(); // Resume rotation
        return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
    }); 

});
```

If anyone cand help me with a hint or maybe a solution, thanks in adnvance!

Answer (score 0):

**reedited**

Try with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var play;                       // missing global var 'play'            

[... other codes...]
```

Comment: Thanks but after I add  clearInterval(play);  the slider is not working anymore, it becomes a static image.

Comment: It's hard to answer without a link to the gallery or a jsfiddle to test it. May you provide some? Thanks!

Comment: actually does not solve the problem even with the add fo var play;
anyway I decided to use another script with less bugs

thanks